# Как получить html блок по его классу в php?

Tags: php, html

Код ниже не работает и я не понимаю что не так. Селектора по классу насколько я понял в php нет, есть только по имени тега и id, но и они не работают.

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('test.html');
$elem = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li');
print_r ($elem);
?>
```

Желательно обойтись без библиотек.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366351/getting-dom-elements-by-classname

Comment: регуляркой проще))